# Regex – looking for help selecting a line and an XML tag immediately preceding it

Tags: regex, xml

Regex noob here. I've been able to piece enough together to get what I need done, with one exception. A little background: I use a drawing program on an iPad which records all drawing steps into a XML script file. After I'm done drawing I export the script file, make some edits to it to clean things up, and then play the script file back on my desktop. What I'm stumped on is I want to remove an "undo" statement and the command immediately preceding it, which is an XML tag. I do this so when I play back the script, all of the undo operations that I made while drawing are removed – hopefully that makes sense.

Here is an example chunk of code. I simplified it a bit but I think I kept the essential parts:

```
<StrokeEvent>
    <StrokeHeader>
        (more content here)
    </StrokeHeader>
    Wait: 0.000s    Loc: (1062.86, 872.169) Pr: 1   Ti: 0.680557    Ro: 0.312818    Fw: 1   Bt: 0   Rv: NO  Iv: NO
    Wait: 0.000s    Loc: (1063.56, 873.09)  Pr: 1   Ti: 0.680557    Ro: 0.312818    Fw: 1   Bt: 0   Rv: NO  Iv: NO
</StrokeEvent>
<StrokeEvent>
    <StrokeHeader>
        (more content here)
    </StrokeHeader>
    Wait: 0.000s    Loc: (1062.86, 872.169) Pr: 1   Ti: 0.680557    Ro: 0.312818    Fw: 1   Bt: 0   Rv: NO  Iv: NO
    Wait: 0.000s    Loc: (1063.56, 873.09)  Pr: 1   Ti: 0.680557    Ro: 0.312818    Fw: 1   Bt: 0   Rv: NO  Iv: NO
</StrokeEvent>
Wait: 2.022s    EvType: Command CommandID: Undo
```

Each ... tag is a drawing stroke. And, the entire file just reads from top to bottom in order that the drawing is made. So, I want to select each entire "Wait" line that has "Undo" at the end AND the first entire ... tag immediately preceding it. I'll delete these two and when I play the script back it will remove that stroke and undo together.

Thanks for any help provided!

Comment: To process XML you need XML tools (an XML parser plus, say, an XPath query library). Don't use regular expressions to parse XML - you'll never get it 100% right, because XML is a recursive grammar, and regular expressions can't handle recursive grammars.

Comment: Yeah, I've heard that elsewhere too. I may have to look into those options. Thanks for the reply.